# Spring, JPA -- testing abstract class

Tags: spring, testing, jpa, integration, abstract

I have a lot of entities in application and I use JPA implementation for persisting them, therefore most of CRUD methods across DAOs are similar (see example class diagram below).

[image]

For this purpose there is interface `DAOTemplate` which contains methods available for all entities and is implemented by abstract class `AbstractDAO`.

Some entities require additional methods such as `findByEmail` for `User` entity. For that purpose there is DAO interface with such methods e.g. `UserDAO`.

Now I want to write integration tests for all methods (those in `DAOTemplate` and `UserDAO`). What is the best solution? Should I somehow (how?) test `AbstractDAO` and then only special methods in `UserDAOTest` or should I test all methods in `UserDAOTest` and also in other test cases for other entities? I'm trying to avoid the second solution because I don't like it.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test all methods in UserDAOTest since calling them will have different results depending on what entity you are trying to persist. You won't only be testing your DAO code but also your entities, their annotations and their relationships.

But in following the DRY principle you should not re-implement the AbstractDAO methods in each test, but you can for instance create an AbstracDAOTest that all UserDAOTest inherits from. Having your tests match your code like that should look quite nice..

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation. If you have a lot of DAO it can be slow to test again same methods.
I created dummy entity and DAO implementation only for testing.